# SUMPRODUCT after SPLIT (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a big list of PVC windows dimensions, which has this kind of structure:

```
2*3
1*2
1*2
```

I want to sum the areas of all windows, which manually looks like this:

```
2*3 + 1*2 + 1*2
```

**How to do it using a dynamic formula?**

First I split cells using the `*` symbol.

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A3;"*"))

2   3
1   2
1   2
```

Then tried a lot of combinations and the closest to desired result is:

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT({A1:A3};"*"))));;1))

6
```

I'm stuck with only one row and don't know how to extend it to the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A3,"*"),0,1) * INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A3,"*"),0,2)))
```

You basically use `SPLIT` twice, once to get the first part (that's what `INDEX` does) and once for the second part of the dimensions. You multiply those, and then `SUM` all the results.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Really nice, simple solution :)